# Stackoverflow Exception with Apache Tiles

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tiles, tiles-3

I have a problem with tiles

I have a template (mainLayout) which does basically the following:

```
<html>
<body>
   ...
   <jsp:include page="/services" />
   ...
</body>
</html>
```

The url `/services` is served by a Spring controller which uses Tiles3. The `/services` url is using a different layout (rawLayout) which just outputs a jsp.

The problem is that the code is generating a stackoverflow error. Actually, when trying to render the `/services` url with a raw layout, Tiles is actually switching to mainLayout.

I debugged Tiles, and even though the definition is correct (rawLayout), the `BasicTilesContainer::getAttributeContext` method is switching back to the originating layout (mainLayout). It seems that Tiles is not using the template from the definition, but takes it from an execution stack.

My tiles definition:

```
<definition name="main" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/layout/mainLayout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="content" value=""/>
</definition>
<definition name="full" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/layout/fullLayout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="content" value=""/>
</definition>

<definition name="services" extends="full">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/services.jsp" />
</definition>
```

I hope this is clear enough.

Thanks

Comment: My guess is that it's infinitely looping because you call `/services`, which is inappropriately using `mainLayout`, which in turn calls `/services`, which uses `mainLayout`, which...you get the point.  So the question is: Why is `/services` using `mainLayout` instead of `rawLayout`.  For that, I think we need to see your tiles config (should be a bunch of XML files that define the "tiles").

Comment: @CodeChimp: Yes I agree this is the problem. I added the XML tiles definition entries.

Comment: I never seen an empty `<put-attribute>` before.  What happens if you remove that in the `full` definition?

Comment: @CodeChimp Same thing

Comment: Is your services.jsp calling something that might be using the same `services` tile definition?